# Unable to select second HDD as backup drive Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I've got two drive on my desktop, a 250GB SSD with my OS, and a 4TB HDD for other files. When I go to Windows 10's settings to create a system image for recovery, it doesn't notice the HDD. I had no issues in Windows 7 with creating an image, and the HDD has an active path, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Win10 sometimes has trouble seeing secondary HDDs until a drive letter is reassigned to them (without partitioning or formatting).  Follow the steps [on this page](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=92#S1).  Relevant excerpts:

- Type `Windows-key+R` to open `run`
- Type `diskmgmt.msc` and click ok
- Right-click on your 4TB HDD and choose `Change Drive Letter and Paths...`
- Click `Change...` and select the letter of your choice, then click ok, ok.
- You may have to reboot afterwards